# r: How to extract month and day for the variable not date format

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, format, lubridate

I have a dateset containing date information.
But I found that this date variable is not date format so `lubridate` package does not work.
Here is my date variable

```
date <-as.character("February 2, 2021")
mdy(date)  
[1] "2021-02-20"
```

So `mdy` function produces incorrect result.
I wonder how to convert this variable into date format or
extract month and day, separately.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `as.Date(date,"%B %d, %Y")`. For the record, `mdy` from `lubridate` gives me the correct output.

Comment: If you read `?as.Date`, you won't find much except a reference to look at `strftime` and `strptime`. And despite the assertion about no help page for `strptime`, if you read `?strptime` you'll see that the format `"%B"` represents the *"Full month name in the current locale"*. With that, you might then try to combine it with `"%d"` (day of the month as a decimal number) and `"%Y"` (year with century, aka 4-digit year). And nicola's suggestion works :-)

Comment: Isn't `"2021-02-20"` the equivalent to  `"February 2, 2021"` ?

Comment: @Trusky No: "2021-02-20" is equivalent to February 20, 2021.

Comment: Missed the 20, my bad.

Comment: I think r2evans is on the right track with the locale bit. What locale are you in? You can type `sessionInfo()$locale` at the R prompt to find out.

Comment: With lubridate  ‘1.7.10’ which is the most recent CRAN version I can't reproduce this.  Note that the as.character is not needed as the argument is already character.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the same piece of code as you

```
library(lubridate)
date <- as.character("February 2, 2021")
mdy(date)
```

I get what I consider a correct output:

```
[1] "2021-02-02"
```

What version of the package `lubridate` are you using? Output above produced with package version 1.7.4, R version 3.6.2.

Comment: Please do not post answers to circumvent the comment anywhere privilege. For questions that you cannot reproduce, [flag the post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for closure due to inability to reproduce. Once you have 50 reputation, you will be able to post messages such as these as [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) under the question.

Comment: Hi @IanCampbell, still a bit new to SO, thanks for the info. Don't see a flag for closure (due to inability to reproduce) though. I would have added my note as a comment but don't have the right to do so due to my low reputation.

Comment: Got it, question flagged, thanks once again. While at it... according to SO standards and rules, should I delete my answer?

Comment: Alright, fair answer. We will see if it helps the questioner - if so and he specifies the question, then this answer is considered useless and should go :)